# blockchain.info JSON API problem

Tags: blockchain, api

I'm trying to get the time series for a specific period from [Blockchain](http://blockchain.info) but the JSON seems to not be there anymore. Does anyone know if the JSON API is not available anymore or it is a temporary issue?

For example when trying to access https://blockchain.info/charts/hash-rate&format=json I get an *Unknown Exception*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error should be fixed now.

https://blockchain.info/charts/hash-rate?format=json

Answer (score 1):

The JSON export seems indeed to be broken. A quick workaround is to simply get the graph page and extract the needed data from there:

```
curl -s https://blockchain.info/charts/hash-rate | grep data: | grep -oE '\[[0-9\.,]+\]'
```

That should give you the JSON array. The array contains a daily sample of the hash-rate starting from timestamp

```
curl -s https://blockchain.info/charts/hash-rate | grep pointStart | grep -oE '[0-9]+'
```